# redirect to static content using JAX-RS UriBuilder

Tags: spring, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Jersey Application and I am trying to redirect to a html page which shows the api console when I access "/apiconsole" endpoint as shown below.

```
/**
 * Redirect to API Console
 *
 * @return API Console
 */
@GET
@Path("/apiconsole")
public Response redirectToApiConsole() {
    //redirect path from baseURI to the api console
    URI redirectedURL = UriBuilder.fromPath("/api/console/index.html").build();
    return Response.seeOther(redirectedURL).build();
}
```

Is this the same as doing this in Spring?

```
/**
 * Redirect to API Console 
 *
 * @return API Console
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/apiconsole", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public View redirectToApiConsole() {
    return new RedirectView("/api/console/index.html?raml=/api/console/api.raml");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use [Viewable](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.8/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/mvc/Viewable.html) to acheive this and have to update the web.xml to include the servlet filter instead of servlet. I have provided an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553719/messagebodywriter-not-found-for-media-type-text-html-but-works-for-json) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553948/getting-404-trying-to-render-a-jsp-from-jersey-2).Hope it helps.

Comment: I get an error `o.g.j.m.i.WriterInterceptorExecutor      : MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/html, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable.`

Comment: I added the following config                                                                 Jersey Config : `property(ServletProperties.FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX,"/((api/console/.*))");`                                                                            customConfig: `property(MvcFeature.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH,"/api/console/");
        register(org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.MvcFeature.class);`                  and simply return this `return new Viewable("index");`

Comment: TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH should be the location of directory of html files. Something like '/WEB-INF' and then change the new Viewable to ("/index"). Also, get rid of the ServletProperties.FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX property.

Comment: My static resources scripts and css are within src/main/java/resources/static/api/console/  folder and so is my index.html. and I am using this FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX property to allow jersey to serve up all files under /api/console/ directory. Without this I am unable to view my static resources from local host directly. Note that I am not using FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404 filter. Thanks for your help!

Comment: MvcFeature ust provides the mvc supporting infrastructute and you'll have to implement your custom support for a templating engine. Jersey provides template implementation for jsp, mustache and free marker templates. Please read this link https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/mvc.html. You can use JspMvcFeature instead of MvcFeature to serve html pages.

Comment: If you're only looking for a redirect than take a look at this example here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728476/jersey-rest-webservice-redirecting-to-the-same-page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113648/discussion-between-shiv-v-and-daredadevil).